# React native I am getting Network Request Failed using fetch to post image

Tags: react-native, server, fetch, blob, image-upload

[image: Error on react native debugger]

I am trying to send blob images to the server but react native is showing the error network failed error.

```
get_data = async () => {
let file = new FormData();

fetch("https://jzzqf.sse.codesandbox.io/", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8",
    //"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
  mode: "no-cors",
  body: file
})
  .then(function(response) {
    alert(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    alert(error);
  });
```

};

Answer (score -1):

Switch your then to handle the promise rejection

```
.then(response => 
  {
    alert(response);
  }, reject => {
    // handle reject here
 })
```

Comment: yes, it is showing error is there a solution to solve error